# Bitbucket with android :"Can't publish part of repository" error

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I have recently use Android studio and I was just try to connect bitbucket with it.
I don't want manually bitbucket by terminal thas why I googling it. find some links [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nHGCFKtYlw) .
I have follow all the steps  install `plugin>shareproject>login>private>share project`

and than  error. I checked my bitbucket but no repositary created.

> **Can't publish part of repository**
>
> Invalid VCS root mapping  The directory
>   ExpandableLayout-master\TestProject is
>   registered as a Git root, but no Git repositories

I don't know is thare error of plugins of bit bucket or my android studio

Comment: Have you installed git on your system?

Comment: obviously @RahulPratapSingh

Comment: I suggest you to download and use sourcetree. Which is a GUI software for your GIT tasks. Go to link https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview/

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh how would that help with errors in Android Studio?

Comment: If you look carefully in the question git is not able to find repository that means he has either not created it or is using wrong directory also in comments section of answer given by VonC, Vishal says that he doesn't want to use terminal so I suggested him to use sourcetree so that he can easily create, clone or use repositories.

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh  bhaii thanks for suggestion it also help me in future thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After to much research... finally i got answer
Actually it is bug of bit-bucket plugin. [bit-bucket bug](https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/issues/11/cant-publish-part-of-repository)

Here is solution given by AKAMUZA in above link thanks bro.

(1)Go to project folder and delete .git folder

(2) IDEA pops up an error message about project not being under version control and an option to **configure** it. Press Configure and just delete the path to your project in VCS section.

(3)After this Import into version control -> Share project works like a charm.

### UPDATE

I Found many developer having **issue after use plugin directly from Android studio** and if It not work you can download below plugin

1. https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-139.224.zip
2. Go to Setting-> Plugin-> **Install plugin From disk** ->above downloaded plugin -> install & resatart.
3. You can feel Magic after restart  :P

Comment: This is not working for me, you see when you remove the .git folder, the VCS state reverts to disabled. If you enabled it back again, it will ask you which one to use, so if you choose git again it will create .git folder

Comment: when you remove .git from file and come to android studio have one popup message or not??

Comment: There is, I remove the git config as you suggested. But when I go to vcs and import to VCS(of course this will not work since I have to reenable the VCS again which creates the .git folder)

Comment: nono  ..i said popup menu on android studio after remove .git file bro.

Comment: I see, the thing is there is no popup button when I did just that. Esp on the top-right corner. Well what did work for me is the most helpful git bash! I just bashed the location and git init there. I also add manually remote repo through the console. AS detects this and happily sync my project to the repo. Thanks a million Vishal Patel!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with android studio.
this is my suggested solution:

go to project root folder
then open a terminal in this folder:

1. git init
2. git add --all
3. git commit -m  "your message"

then go to bitbucket and create new repository then choose "I have an existing project" ...

Now you can use plugin to push/update

Answer (score 2):

This thread mentions (assuming that `File > Settings > Version Control` is set to "git"):

> You could instead have navigated into the directory via a terminal or shell and typed '`git init`'. That would have converted that directory into a git repository.

So check if `ExpandableLayout-master\TestProject` has or has not yet a `.git` subfolder in it.
If not, it means you have declared that path as a git repo, but locally, on your disk, that folder is not yet a git repo. If so, you can initialize it, add a remote pointing to an empty bitbucket repo and push.

Comment: i give details that i dont want to use terminal bro.
becasue i dont underatnde it well first time user. of git can u help me

Comment: @VishalPatel Don't be afraid of the terminal: just `cd` into that folder, do a simple `ls -alrt` and see if there is a `.git` subfolder or not. Also, do you have that same `TestProject` (with files in it) already in a Bitbucket repo?

Comment: @VishalPatel a possible cause for that type of error is that your project folder is not yet a git repo: that would manifest as "no `.git` in it". Hence my suggestion to go in a file explorer or a console and have a look: is there or is there not a `.git` folder?

Comment: @VishalPatel you have git.exe, which is good. But my question is: is there a `.git/` (dot git) subfolder in your project main directory `ExpandableLayout-master\TestProject`?

Comment: Can't publish reposioty

Comment: Did you push the repo to your bitbucket repo? (as in https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5512045;jsessionid=2FC823363493952D5A3B52A03736E65F)

Comment: thanks for help finaly i got answer from bug bitbucket

Comment: @VishalPatel yes, but with a separate question, you can add an answer (answering your own question), and help everybody else.

Comment: you mean i post new question with more detail and add my answer at ther with own answer sir?

Comment: @VishalPatel I didn't saw your answer above at first: you already did post an answer so this is enough.